# Is there any change in the special editions in favour or against the Star Wars Ring Theory?

Tags: star-wars

Briefly, the [Star Wars Ring Theory](http://www.starwarsringtheory.com) states that the Star Wars prequels were intentionally composed such that they form a ring composition with the original trilogy, with many intentional similarities connecting certain movies in a certain way (see below), in particular in terms of plot development and scene compositions, namely:

- Episode I is parallel to Episode VI.
- Episode II is anti-parallel to Episode V.
- Episode III is sort-of anti-parallel to Episode IV.

Assuming that this is true, it is pretty unlikely that this was intended like this from the beginning given the history of Star Wars. Thus the original trilogy could not have been designed to facilitate this composition and all the matchings had to be made in the prequels with the orginal trilogy being mostly fixed. This question is about the *mostly.*

If the theory is true, it is entirely plausible that Lucas had already planned the intended composition when making the special editions (which came out two years before Episode I). It would therefore be interesting to see, if he introduced any changes that can be regarded as working towards this composition – which would be an evidence for the Ring Theory. On the other hand, there could also be evidence against it, namely changes that are significantly opposing this compositon.

Are there any such changes?

Answer (score 3):

I have looked through the changes with the special edition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_changes_in_Star_Wars_re-releases). In retrospect I would say most of the substantial changes are cosmetic. Or do very little to add to the ring theory.

However this is not true of the Saga edition and the 2004 re release. These have a couple things that do help this theory.

The infamous 'Noooooo!' that was added when Vader is saving Luke from the Emperor is I believe the same sound that was used in episode III when Vader rises (after thinking that he has killed his wife and children).

Also the addition of Hayden Christensen at his funeral.

This gives a strong link between EP III and VI, which to me would seem more like anti parallels. In one Anakin falls to the dark side, in the other he is redeemed.